# Parse JSON with Decodable return empty Model

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, jsonparser, jsondecoder

I'm trying to load local `JSON` file and parse using model which conforms to `Decodable` protocol.

JSON file:

```
[
{
    "body": {},
    "header": {
        "returnCode": "200",
        "returnMessage": "Successfully Received",
    }
}
]
```

Response Message model:

```
struct ResponseMessage: Decodable {

    struct header: Decodable {
        let returnCode: String
        let returnMessage: String
    }
}
```

Mock API implementation:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "MockJSONData", withExtension: "json")!
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let teams = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseMessage.self, from: data)
                print(teams)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
```

But Response Message returns empty data for that.

Appreciate your help and suggestions!

Thanks

Comment: Your JSON is an array, so it should be `decode([ResponseMessage].self`, and it's missing `struct ResponseMessage: Decodable { let header: header }`. And btw, write `struct Header: Decodable {` instead with an uppercase, and then `struct ResponseMessage: Decodable { let header: Header }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update `ResponseMessage` and `Header` types as below,

```
struct ResponseMessage: Decodable {
    var header: Header
}


struct Header: Decodable {
    let returnCode: String
    let returnMessage: String
}
```

and `decode` like this,

```
do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    let teams = try JSONDecoder().decode([ResponseMessage].self, from: data)
    print(teams.first!.header.returnMessage)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```